# Li-Ion Battery Swelling Mechanism

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, reliability

I have recently had both a tablet (manufactured 2013) and a phone (manufactured 2017) battery
swell (both batteries are Li-ion).  The photo below shows the tablet's damage.  Both
batteries still worked after swelling.  Though it's possible that the swelling was gradual
over many months, I doubt this and am more inclined to believe that it all happened within
one day.

Actually, I believe both were dropped while fully-charged (probably even dropped while plugged
in to the charger), and suspect the impact this caused played a role.  I assume most Li-ion
batteries out in the world, if they never experienced an impact, show no swelling all the way
till end of life.  Please correct me if this assumption is wrong.

So, what is the chemical mechanism by which impact causes a battery to swell?  Is the swelling
more likely if the battery is fully-charged during impact?  Does it matter whether the charger
was connected during impact or would the same swelling have occurred if I had disconnected the
charger 5 seconds before impact?

Or, is it more likely that impact played no role in my damage?

[image: battery swelling]

Comment: Sounds like you are continuing to use them. You should stop that and find the proper way recycle/dispose of the swelled batteries. Damaged Li-Ion batteries are extremely dangerous. There is a strong reason that the Samsung Galaxy Note 7's are no longer allowed on airplanes.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time the swilling is due to a physical distruction of the separator between the two battery poles which leads to a chemical reaction between the two electrolytes.

Although you can still measure battery voltage, I assume that no significant current is available.

I strongly recommend storing the battery in a fireprove environment and bring it to a recycling facility as soon as possible. Under no circumstances I would try to recharge the device.

Comment: Ok, but good current was still available for both the tablet and the phone (and I understand I am taking a safety risk...I don't want to discuss that further, but in case it makes you feel better, I have replaced the tablet battery). Based on your comments and experience, I am leaning towards the impact causing my swelling.  I still am curious however if I am more susceptible to swelling because I keep my devices fully-charged (and plugged-in most of the time), so hoping for more answers...

Comment: There are many reasons for swelling. Most of them are using the battery out of their comfort zone. Too hot e.g. leaving it in sun, dropping the device, deep discharging, overcharging. If your device is working correct, overcharging should not be a problem even if you keep it plugged in all the time. But keep in mind, the cell will age much faster if it is permanently stored fully charged.